# Sending money from address to address on bitcoind with PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm programming the back-end for an ecommerce solution, Bitcoind API gives me one way of sending money to a bitcoin address: `sendfrom <fromaccount> <tobitcoinaddress> <amount>`

If I understood well, this will transfer money from one account to an address, but I don't see any way of sending from address to address. I didn't implemented accounts on my backend system, and don't want to do it as it's an aditional layer of complexity that I don't want to deal with right now.

So, I supose this will grab money from whatever address/addresses asociated to the account and send them to the bitcoin address provided. Any way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `getaccount <bitcoinaddress>`: "Returns the account associated with the given address." You give it a bitcoin address, receive the corresponding account, and can then use that account to `sendfrom`.

However, for security reasons, I advise against sending payments directly from PHP running on a web server. You may want to introduce at least one additional layer of validation before actual payment, and that layer is probably running on a separate machine. For example, have PHP write the payment orders to the database for another application elsewhere to poll and process. Both applications will have access to the database, but no direct link between them; and the PHP side will not (have to) be authorized to access the BTC wallet at all. Also consider using hot and cold wallets.

Comment: I think I know what I'll do, sending money from address to address asociated to account named `CASHOUT` with `move` command. This won't apply any fees ar won't give me any troubles. Then for cashing out all the money to a wallet outside the server I'll use `sendfrom CASHOUT <externalbtcaddress> <amount>`. Only problem I've got now is `sendfrom` cand send money even if the account hasn't got enough for paying the fees, but another address on the wallet can. This will put `CASHOUT` account on red numbers, and will take the btcs for the fees from another address... But that's another question ;)

Comment: Did you see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained#Sending already? It says "There is no way to ask Bitcoin to "create a payment transaction using the coins received from these previously received transactions" without using the raw transactions API". So, basically, you're not supposed to want to send from one specific address, but just let bitcoind decide on how many BTC from which previous transaction(s) to send.

Comment: That doesn't make sense when just a bit down after that you can read:  `- The check for sufficient funds is done before paying transaction fees (if any); if a
   transaction fee is needed, and there are sufficient funds in the wallet, then the
   transaction fee will be paid and debited from the account.  For example, if account
   'foo' contains 10 bitcoins, you sendfrom foo 15VjRaDX9zpbA8LVnbrCAFzrVzN7ixHNsC 10,
   and the transaction costs 0.01, 'foo's balance will be -0.01 bitcoins.` ¿Didn't this mean that I can send from specific accounts?

Comment: Yes, you can send from a specific *account*. The account, however, is a  purely virtual view onto your wallet. That's why an *account* can have a negative balance; your *wallet*, however, cannot. I found the "Introduction" on that page quite illustrating: The wallet is the bank's vault; coins are deposited and withdrawn, individual accounts can go negative. The customer cannot request to receive the exact coins he deposited; he will be given a mix of coins from the vault that were deposited by other customers. Your wallet's accounts are just for your own bookkeeping.

Comment: Imagine you receive BTC 5 on address A, plus BTC 5 on address B. Then you send BTC 8 to some other address. There's no single *address* under your control which has a balance of 8 or more. Yet, bitcoind will allow you to transfer BTC 8, possibly taking BTC 5 from the previous transation to address A and another 3 from the previous transaction to address B. Whether A and B are regarded as the same account or not does not make a difference on which coins are sent.